# Integrating monkey talk to static Framework(iOS)

Tags: ios, monkeytalk

Let me Describe my problem more .We are building static library(iOS) with resources in bundle and we are using that static library to other project.When we integrate monkey talk to our project .It will not detect some of the Views and script fails.Can anybody let me know, whats wrong we are doing here.(We are integrating monkey talk library to our iOS project, Not to our static library).

Any guide will be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

You can select row by it's index like this:

```
    var id = 1;

    app.table().selectIndex(id,{thinktime:"2000"});
    app.device.back({thinktime:"2000"});

    id++;

    app.table().selectIndex(id,{thinktime:"2000"});
    app.device.back({thinktime:"2000"});
```

You can do this in loop if you have more rows in table.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a thinktime of 5 or 6 second while tapping.

Comment: we tried that still it's not detecting any element which are on the view.